# batch script that converts date to julian date

Tags: batch-file, julian-date

Im creating a batch file to convert %date% into julian date but I seem to not find clear information on to do this. Anyone can tell me how to convert %date% to julian date? or any batch file that exist that already those this?

Thank you

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a batch file out on the web to convert a date into just about any format you want.

Comment: If you hover over the julian-date tag it says: The term "Julian date" also refers to the day-of-year number (more properly, the **ordinal date**) in the Gregorian calendar, especially in computer programming, the military and the food industry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Original code modified to just show the Julian Day Number of current date in "Dow MM/DD/YYYY" format:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set /A "a=(%%a-14)/12, JDN=(1461*(%%c+4800+a))/4+(367*(%%a-2-12*a))/12-(3*((%%c+4900+a)/100))/4+%%b-32075"
)
echo %JDN%
```

Reference: http://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm#comp

**2nd. EDIT**

To get the *ordinal day number*, based on the number of days in the year (from 1 to 366), use this method:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set /A "MM=1%%a-100, DD=1%%b-100, Ymod4=%%c%%4"
)
for /F "tokens=%MM%" %%m in ("0 31 59 90 120 151 181 212 243 273 304 334") do set /A Day=DD+%%m
if %Ymod4% equ 0 if %MM% gtr 2 set /A Day+=1

echo %Day%
```

Comment: It returns a  Missing operand error when I run that batch.

Comment: Of course! This is _not_ a working Batch file, but just two subroutines that do the conversion process. If you want a _complete_ Batch file, then you first show us what is the format of the `%date%` you want to convert: MM/DD/YYYY, DD/MM/YYYY, any other? Is the date the current one? Is it given as parameter? Etc...

Comment: Example of the %date% format from the command prompt:
>echo %date%
>Wed 01/13/2016

Comment: It returns 2457401 I think its incorrect,  I believe its suppose to return 013 which is today julian date.

Comment: @Hereok You are confusing Julian date with Ordinal date.

Comment: Im referen to this julian date [Please view this link](http://computerequipment.tpub.com/TM-11-5895-1412-12P/img/TM-11-5895-1412-12P_243_1.jpg)

Comment: Nope.  That is ordinal date.  Read Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date

Comment: Well, if this answer give the same result of the other answer (2457401), both methods should be correct, right? Did you read the description at the `julian` tag you used in your question? "Now, April 13, 2011 (UTC) the Julian day number is 2455665". Anyway, read my second edit...

Comment: @Aacini, that is much shorter code then the one I had been using from this site: http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdfuncs/dandt/#datetoordinal

Answer (score 1):

With [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759992/calculating-jdayjulian-day-in-javascript) here's a julian.bat:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off

    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" 

    exit /b %errorlevel%

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */


Date.prototype.getJulian = function() {
    return Math.floor((this / 86400000) - (this.getTimezoneOffset()/1440) + 2440587.5);
}

var today = new Date(); //set any date
var julian = today.getJulian(); //get Julian counterpart
WScript.Echo(julian);
```

And it can be used like:

```
for /f %%a in ('call julian.bat') do @set "julian=%%a"
```

Comment: Hello I tried that script and the result is 2457401 I believe that incorrect. It shoul return 013 which is today julian date. Any thought in why its returning 2457401?

Comment: @Hereok I've tried [this](http://www.onlineconversion.com/julian_date.htm) and [this](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php) and few more and results are consistent with these in the script

Answer (score 1):

@Aacini - your answer works perfectly ... unless month or date is 08 or 09 - then batch gets confused and thinks it's an attempt at an illegal octal. I do not see how to keep it on a single line anymore, but here's a solution (tested, and incorporating @jeb comment):

```
:get_julian
    for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%1") do (
        set /a mon=100%%a %% 100
        set /a day=100%%b %% 100
        set year=%%c
    )
    set /a x=(mon-14)/12
    set /a JD=(1461*(year+4800+x))/4+(367*(mon-2-12*x))/12-(3*((year+4900+x)/100))/4+day-32075
    exit /b
```

Comment: You can use `set /a "mon=(100%mon%) %% 100"`

Comment: Does the "@" tag work in a message body, or do I need to put @Aacini here for him to see it?

Comment: Neither one way nor the other, but you could add a comment under his answer

Comment: @jeb - No, I can't.  I already tried that. Not yet 50 rep, so I can't comment on a post that is not mine.